# Subtracting values group-wise by the average of each group in R

Tags: r, aggregate

I am trying to subtract group means from each group's values.

For example:

```
> x <- data.frame('gene' = c('A','A','A','B','B','C','C','C'),'value' = c(32.3,31,30.5,25,22.1,20.5,21.2,19.8))
> x
  gene value
1    A  32.3
2    A  31.0
3    A  30.5
4    B  25.0
5    B  22.1
6    C  20.5
7    C  21.2
8    C  19.8
```

I can find the group means:

```
> aggregate(x[,2],list(x$gene),mean)
  Group.1        x
1       A 31.26667
2       B 23.55000
3       C 20.50000
```

How do I subtract the "value" in x by the corresponding group mean? My desire result is as follow:

```
   gene value-group.mean
1    A  1.03333
2    A  -0.26667
3    A  -0.76667
4    B  1.45
5    B  -1.45
6    C  0
7    C  0.7
8    C  -0.7
```

How can I do it in R?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the library `dplyr`, you can do:

```r
library(dplyr)
x %>%
  group_by(gene) %>%
  mutate_all(funs(.-mean(.)))

# A tibble: 8 x 2
# Groups:   gene [3]
  gene   value
  <fct>  <dbl>
1 A      1.03 
2 A     -0.267
3 A     -0.767
4 B      1.45 
5 B     -1.45 
6 C      0    
7 C      0.700
8 C     -0.700
```

Comment: What does %>% mean? Thanks.

Comment: It's called a `pipe`, you can found more definition here on the package [`magrittr`](https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/reference/pipe.html). Briefly, it allows to pass successive operations without to called back the previous object. For example `x %>% head` is the same than doing `head(x)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ave()` to achieve it when with `base R`, and in that case you don't need to apply `aggregate` intermediately:

```
x$value_group.mean <- with(x,value-ave(value,gene))
```

such that

```
> x
  gene value value_group.mean
1    A  32.3        1.0333333
2    A  31.0       -0.2666667
3    A  30.5       -0.7666667
4    B  25.0        1.4500000
5    B  22.1       -1.4500000
6    C  20.5        0.0000000
7    C  21.2        0.7000000
8    C  19.8       -0.7000000
```

Answer (score 3):

A `data.table` method:

```
require(data.table)

setDT(x)[, `value-group.mean` := mean(value), by = gene][, `value-group.mean` := value - `value-group.mean`]

x
#   gene value value-group.mean
# 1:    A  32.3        1.0333333
# 2:    A  31.0       -0.2666667
# 3:    A  30.5       -0.7666667
# 4:    B  25.0        1.4500000
# 5:    B  22.1       -1.4500000
# 6:    C  20.5        0.0000000
# 7:    C  21.2        0.7000000
# 8:    C  19.8       -0.7000000
```

Answer (score 1):

Modifying Khaynes answer to separate the the aggregation and subtraction by adding the use of `merge`.

```
x <- data.table(gene = c('A','A','A','B','B','C','C','C'), value = c(32.3,31,30.5,25,22.1,20.5,21.2,19.8) )
x_gene_mean <- x[,.(group_mean=mean(value)),keyby=gene]

x_2=special_function(x)#Perform any needed operation against x to obtain x_2

x_2 <- merge(x,x_gene_mean,by="gene")
x_2[, anomaly := value - group_mean]
```

Why it is important to separate:

1. x is the original data. This can be referred to long-term data.
2. x_gene_mean is the group mean. This can be referred as climatology.
3. x undergoes an analysis, for example, finding extreme event in x, based on threshold of magnitude, value, and ratio. x_2 is now the extreme events found in x. x_2 is also a small fraction of x. This can be referred as selected/extreme events in the long-term data.
4. To calculate the anomaly of x_2, you need to subtract x_2 with the group mean of x (not x_2), which is the x_gene_mean. This can be referred to as the anomaly of selected/extreme events with respect to the climatology in the long-term data.

This is the normal method in earth science. To find the anomaly of a selected case, it must be subtracted against the climatology in the original long-term data.